# Homogeneous regular (= polynomial component) maps with odd degree and their being global homeomorphisms in dimensions higher than one?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, polynomials, differential-topology

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^m \to\mathbb{R}^m, F:=(F_1\dots F_m)$ be a regular map, i.e. with components $F_i$ that are polynomials.

Assume further that each $F_i$ is an odd degree (say $d$) homogenous polynomial. We denote this by saying that $F$ is a **homogeneous, odd degree, regular map of degree $d.$**

**Questions:**  **Is $F$ a global homeomorphism?** I don't think so (an example below, in dimension two). Well, then *after* we assume that we assume that $F$ is a local homeomorphism, does this mean $F$ is a global homeomorphism?

**Motivation to ask this question:** This is true in **dimension one**, i.e. when $m=1,$ for in this case the only regular maps are the polynomials of the form $x\mapsto x^d, d$ odd, which is clearly a homeomorphism (but *not a diffeomorhism* because the inverse *isn't* differentiable at zero).

In **dimension two**, one can consider the homogeneous regular map of degree $3$ defined by $(x,y)\mapsto (x^3-3xy^2, 3x^2y-y^3),$ which is writing the complex map $z\mapsto z^3: \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ in real co-ordinates, and this is neither a local nor global homeomorphism, even though it's surjective.

**Pertinent thoughts:**

(1) **Essentially we'll need to show that $F$ is a covering map**, and then use the simple connectedness of $\mathbb{R}^m$ to conclude global homeomorphism.

(2) **To go from local homeomorphism to covering map** (see (1) above), we need two things:

(i) **properness** (cf. [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860351/a-proper-local-diffeomorphism-between-manifolds-is-a-covering-map), albeit they're assuming local diffeomorphism, but I'm hoping that a local homeomorphism may do the job (Will it though? I didn't think this deeper...)), i.e. the inverse image by $F$ of a compact subset must be a compact one. But this raises the question: **is a regular, odd degree, homogenous map, proper**? It is in one dimension, and the polynomial doesn't even have to be homogeneous or odd degree!

(i) **Surjectivity of $F:$** This raises the question: **is a regular, odd degree, homogenous map, surjective**? It is in one dimension, and the polynomial doesn't even have to be homogeneous but needs to have odd degree!

Relevant questions:

(i) [When does local invertibility imply invertibility?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10147/when-does-local-invertibility-imply-invertibility)

(ii) [My own unanswered quesition asking for a sufficient condition to invert a regular map](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460175/is-there-any-sufficient-or-equivalent-condition-for-the-invertibility-of-a-regul)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is **yes**.

> If a homogeneous polynomial map $F:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is a local homeomorphism, then it is a  global homeomorphism.

We say that a map is *proper* if preimages of compact sets are compact.
A *local homeomorphism* $f:X\to Y$ is a map that is a homeomorphism in a neighborhood of each point $x\in X$ (onto the image of that neighborhood).
The following result is well known, see [1,2], and also Chapter 4, Section 2.43 in [3].

> **Theorem.** Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are path-connected Hausdorff spaces, where $Y$ is simply connected. Then a local homeomorphism $f:X\to Y$ is a global homeomorphism of $X$ onto $Y$ if and only if $f$ is a proper map.

Note that in general, a local homeomorphism need not be surjective, and surjectivity is a part of the theorem. The main idea of the proof is to show that a proper local homeomorphism between path connected Hausdorff spaces is a covering map and then the result follows from general facts about covering spaces.

According to the result it suffices to show that $F$ is proper.

Note that $F(x)\neq 0$ for $|x|=1$. Indeed, if $F(x)=0$ for some $x$ with $|x|=1$, then $F(tx)=0$ for $t>0$ by homogeneity of the polynomial and that contradicts the assumption that $F$ is a local homeomorphism.

Assume that $F$ is homogeneous of degree $d$. Since $F\neq 0$ on the unit sphere, $M:=\inf_{|x|=1}|F(x)|>0$ and hence $F(x)\geq M|x|^d$. Therefore, $|F(x)|\to\infty$ as $|x|\to\infty$ and it follows that $F$ is proper.

[1] *Ho, Chung-Wu*, [**When are immersions diffeomorphisms?**](https://doi.org/10.4153/CMB-1981-074-5), Can. Math. Bull. 24, 491-492 (1981). [ZBL0472.57019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0472.57019).

[2] *Ho, Chung-wu*, [**A note on proper maps**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2039880), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 51, 237-241 (1975). [ZBL0273.54007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0273.54007).

[3] *Prasolov, V. V.*, Elements of combinatorial and differential topology. Transl. from the Russian by Olga Sipacheva, Graduate Studies in Mathematics 74. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 0-8218-3809-1/hbk). xii, 331 p. (2006). [ZBL1098.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1098.57001).

Comment: Thanks Piotr for validating and your upcoming answer, I'll wait for the proof then :)

It'll be also nice to see if the homogeneiity assumption is playing a part in your proof!

Comment: Than you for your answer, but don't we also have to show that the regular map $F$ is onto?

Comment: @Learningmath I added some explanations. I think they answer your question.

Comment: Many thanks Piotr, accepted as an answer. I see how you explored the fact that $F$ is homogeneous to conclude that it never vanishes on the unit sphere, in order for it to be a local homeomorphism. I appreciate the argument, and this won't generalize to inhomogeneous polynomials.

Comment: P.S. I suspect that a homogeneous regular function of odd degree $d$ whose coefficients are all positive and also has every diagonal/unmixed term "$x_i^d$" with positive coefficients must be a local homeomorphism. For example, I think $(x,y)\to (x^3 +x^2y + y^3, 3x^3 + 10xy^2 + 2y^3)$ is a local and thus global homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^3.$ I did some tests on the signs of Hessians but couldn't contradict this, but I'm yet to prove it, but I may ask a question about this soon, and refer to your answer..